# Background job creation failed. See inner exception for details

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire, asp.net-core-3.1, background-task

I have the following code that attempts to queue a background job in ASP.Net-Core 3.1 application.

```
public void UpdateStudentBills(object sender, StudentEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => AddStudentToApplicableBills(eventArgs.Student));
    }
```

When I run the application I get the above error message. So, the part of the process meant to be carried out by that line of code does not get executed but every other part of the application runs.

I have tried as follows to log the error and check for what the exception could be, but I find no error logged

```
try{
....
}catch(Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogDebug(e.InnerException.Message);
    }
```

When I run the code outside the Hangfire enqueuing as follows:

```
public void UpdateStudentBills(object sender, StudentEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        AddStudentToApplicableBills(eventArgs.Student);
    }
```

it works as expected.

I do not know how to find out what is making the background job to fail.
Meanwhile, I have another background task on the same application and that other one runs well with Hangfire as a background task as expected

I look forward to a guide to make this work with Hangfire background enqueuing

Comment: Start with catching and logging the exception and see where that leads you.

Comment: That error message is indicating that the exception contains another, probably more descriptive exception, and you need to get at that. So I suggest you add a try / catch around that method call, catch the exception, and then use the ```Exception.InnerException``` property and log the inner exception. Update with results as that will provide a lot more insight.

Comment: My worry is that I do not encounter any error when I run the code without queuing it as a background job

Comment: Use e.ToString() to get the entire exception. This should help decipher the actual issue